# A list of different things without inheritance?

Tags: rust

I know how to make a list of related things in a language with inheritance like Java or an untyped language like JavaScript, but I cannot figure out how to do it in Rust. This will yield an error because the size of the array in `Dereference` is not known at compile time.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct Appearance<'a> {
    identity:   &'a u64, 
    role:       &'a str
}

struct Dereference<'a> {
    set:        [&'a Appearance<'a>]
}

fn main() {
    let r = "hair_color";
    let i1 = 42;
    let i2 = 43;
    let a1 = Appearance{identity: &i1, role: r};
    let a2 = Appearance{identity: &i2, role: r};
    let d1 = Dereference{set: [&a1]};
    let d2 = Dereference{set: [&a1, &a2]};
    let list: Vec<Dereference> = vec!(d1, d2);
}
```

However, the `set` member in `Dereference` will be of arrays up to a small size. Let's say less than 32, and most often 1 or 2, rarely 3, and almost non-existantly larger than that. I could create 32 structs and 32 lists, but for convenience I really would like to do this in a smarter way. At least a single list would help a lot, even if I have to create 32 structs. I need this to be memory and performance efficient at the same time. How do I achieve this in Rust?

Comment: Do you need `Dereference` struct? [You can use slices directly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=16de06c82ec2ddbe2f288386aa5336d8&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: I believe I do, since a reference to Dereference will be contained in another struct named Posit and I will need a lookup table from an instance of Dereference to all instances of Posit that reference that particular instance.

Comment: It's not a problem. You can just use `&[Appearance]` instead of `&Derefenence<'a>`. But it's worth remembering that Rust uses structural equality by default. If two references point to different but equal structures, they are considered equal.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with inheritance; the type `[&'a Appearance<'a>]` is an unsized type. It can only be referenced behind a pointer, as in `&[&'a Appearance<'a>]`

What you probably want is `Vec<&'a Appearance<'a>>`. Really, `Vec<Appearance>` might be better, with `#[derive(Copy)]` on `Appearance`, since `Appearance` itself is a bunch of references and there's not much point taking a reference to a bunch of references.

---

While your example doesn't try making a list of related things, (it just makes a list of `Appearance`s), there are two ways to do this in Rust. One is to use an enum, i.e. you do something like `enum Things {Thing1(Type1), Thing2(Type2), ...}`, and store a `Vec<Things>`. This avoids extra allocation, but is a bit more typing. Alternatively, you can use trait objects, by defining a trait with all the methods you need, implementing it for the relevant types, and using a `Vec<&TraitName>` or `Vec<Box<TraitName>>`.

Comment: Here is a playground of your suggestion, using enum: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1af8376b839d04cc0108647a05d04a96&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: It turns out the enum will be sized by the largest of its members, and since most of the arrays will be unary or binary, the following solution seems better: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0039bd821df7e7771496b09a34fec765&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 0):

An array in Rust is only useful when you know its size at compile-time, for example:

```
struct 3DPoint {
    position: [f32; 3],
    // etc.
}
```

When you do not know the size at compile-time, use a dynamic array, called `Vec`:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct Appearance<'a> {
    identity:   &'a u64, 
    role:       &'a str
}

struct Dereference<'a> {
    set:        Vec<&'a Appearance<'a>>
}

fn main() {
    let r = "hair_color";
    let i1 = 42;
    let i2 = 43;
    let a1 = Appearance{identity: &i1, role: r};
    let a2 = Appearance{identity: &i2, role: r};
    let d1 = Dereference{set: [&a1]};
    let d2 = Dereference{set: [&a1, &a2]};
    let list: Vec<Dereference> = vec!(d1, d2);
}
```

When you develop in Rust, always think in terms of stack. If I understand well your question, you want to pile up things without specify the size: that is impossible.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that 32 different structs, one for each size of set using arrays would make such instances end up on the stack, whereas the lists always would be on the heap. In a language with inheritance I could create a superclass Dereference and then implement 32 different subclasses, while still having a single list based on the superclass. Is that not possible in Rust?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question... It is not possible yet (the feature is coming soon), but even if it were possible, you cannot create a vector of different "subclasses" (to use your word) without boxing them, *i.e.* putting them in the heap. I will update my answer accordingly, but for now I do not have time.